# "Questions with similar titles..." dialog loads multiple instances

Tags: bug, asking-questions, title, similar-questions

**Steps to repro:**

1. Ask a question with the below title and tab away / leave the title box:

   > how can i fix my issue
2. The below validation warning shows up:

[image]

3. If you don't dismiss it, and go back to edit the title to the below and and tab away again:

   > how can i fix my issue now
4. Then to:

   > how can i fix my issue now quickly

If you go to dismiss the dialog now, there will be multiple stacked instances of the dialog for each warning, so you have to dismiss them all. *Possibly by design for users that encounter that type of error.*

I'm aware it's a small issue, but there only needs to be a single instance of the dialog if the same warning is fired multiple times and it's not dismissed.